# .htaccess 301 redirecting folder to absolute url?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hey I'm just setting up a few 301 redirects but I can't work out how to do this particular function.

I have a ton of pages on my existing site e.g.

*/products/23 

/products/3

/products/57

/products/36*

..etc

That I all want to point to one page on a new domain .e.g.
*http://www.mynewdomain.com/store*

I've tried a few RewriteRules with no success!

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2):

It should work with a RedirectMatch directive (although you don't specify in your question how to pass the product codes to the new page):

```
RedirectMatch301 ^/products/(.*) http://www.mynewdomain.com/store/$1
```

This rule will redirect `/products/NNN` to `http://www.mynewdomain.com/store/NNN` (with HTTP status code 301).

Comment: This rule will only redirect /products/10 to /10.

Comment: @develroot thanks and sorry, it was a typo. I corrected the regex.